# Kernel module timer kills system

Tags: c, timer, linux-kernel

I would like to call a function multiple times with timer.
To implement this, I used [this](http://www.embeddedcircle.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=3) example. It works without any error by default.

When I integrated this code snippet inside my source code, it lead to kernel panic (?). There's a long error, and the virtual machine stops working
.

The error printed on the console:

```
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12bf6ae>] ? no_context+0x14b/0x155       
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12bf7ca>] ? bad_area_nosemaphore+0xa/0xc                     
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12c7370>] ? do_page_fault+0x1bf/0x35e
[ 1130.520474]  [<c100d6bf>] ? show_trace_log_lvl+0x37/0x3d                     
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12c71b1>] ? vmalloc_fault+0x87/0x87                     
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12c5377>] ? error_code+0x67/0x6c                             
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12c306e>] ? __schedule+0x31/0x5a4                            
[ 1130.520474]  [<c100fa07>] ? sched_clock+0x9/0xd      
[ 1130.520474]  [<c1051896>] ? sched_clock_local+0x10/0x14b
[ 1130.520474]  [<c102abe2>] ? test_tsk_need_resched+0xa/0x13
[ 1130.520474]  [<c102abe2>] ? test_tsk_need_resched+0xa/0x13              
[ 1130.520474]  [<c102e59c>] ? check_preempt_curr+0x48/0x58                     
[ 1130.520474]  [<c121f462>] ? __napi_complete+0x1b/0x22                        
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12213f0>] ? napi_complete+0x25/0x31
[ 1130.520474]  [<f825d2d6>] ? e1000_clean+0x33e/0x35c [e1000]
[ 1130.520474]  [<c105daf5>] ? arch_local_irq_save+0xf/0x14
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12c45a2>] ? _raw_spin_lock_irq+0x9/0x12                 
[ 1130.520474]  [<c1042307>] ? run_timer_softirq+0x1eb/0x1f3                   
[ 1130.520474]  [<c107b86c>] ? __rcu_process_callbacks+0x5f/0x252              
[ 1130.520474]  [<c103cfdb>] ? local_bh_enable+0x2/0x2               
[ 1130.520474]  [<c103d0dc>] ? __do_softirq+0x101/0x12f
[ 1130.520474]  [<c103c6e8>] ? __local_bh_enable+0x37/0x67                      
[ 1130.520474]  <IRQ>  [<c10cd712>] ? sys_write+0x58/0x61                       
[ 1130.520474]  [<c12c8e5f>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x28
```

I suppose my problem is that a new call is triggered before the previous is returned.

To test this, I modified the above referenced timer toy example:

```
int i;

void timer1_routine(unsigned long data)
{
    int no;
    no=i;
    i++;
    printk(KERN_INFO "process %d starts",no);

    msleep(5000);

    printk(KERN_INFO "process %d ends",no);

    mod_timer(&timer1, jiffies + HZ); /* restarting timer */
}
```

This leads to the same error, so I suppose that my guess is right: there's a conflict between the calls. My question is how can I avoid this problem, if I don't know how much time the execution of the function takes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linux kernel has two main types of context: process context and atomic context.  You're used to things that run in process context.  Atomic context is used primarily for interrupts, both hardware and software.  Kernel timers run from a software interrupt (atomic context).  Code running in atomic context has a number of restrictions, including a prohibition on sleeping.  This explains the crash.

You almost certainly want a `workqueue` instead of a timer.  Workqueue functions execute in process context, so you are allowed to sleep.  If you're going to be working at this level of the kernel, you really need to read this chapter of LDD3: http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch07.pdf